# Inbox message in android

Tags: android

How can I access messages in android?
is there a separate method which enables reading from inbox?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for accessing SMS messages, but it's not documented in the public SDK. If you use [`ContentResolver.query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) with a `Uri` of `content://sms` you should be able to access these messages.

You can find more information [on this Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/2e049e79f88d95d5) or [previous questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+sms+inbox).

You can also try this:

```
public List<String> getSMS(){
     List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
               String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
               String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
              sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);  

          }
        return sms;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you*re talking about the SMS-Inbox. In this case, you would use the [SMSManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) ([Demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/SmsMessagingDemo.html)).

Attention: The SMS Manager from the "android.telephony**.gsm**.SmsManager" Package is deprecated. Use the SMS Manager from the "android.telephony.SmsManager"-Package.